# Repairing and reinstalling Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot

On my Laptop I am using Windows 7 Home Basic. Along with this I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 using WUBI, and in Another partition of my hard disk I also installed Ubuntu 11.04.

If I repair Windows 7 with its bootable CD, or reinstall it, what could be the impact on the two Ubuntu installations?
Will repairing remove the 1st one, and will the grub installed by the partioned Ubuntu (i.e. the 2nd one) be removed?

Comment: I am not sure but I think that repairing windows 7 will not affect your Ubuntu at all in any way what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain (through experience) that the system installed by wubi will be affected; you boot it through the windows bootloader and it is stored in a "virtual partition" (ie a big file) within windows. Best scenario is you recover it with wubi, worst (and my experience) is the system becomes irrecoverable. However, any other system wouldn't be affected.